# Jade extends not working with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I don't know what I am doing wrong but extend doesn't working in my case.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');


var app = require('express')();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'moj-sekret'
}));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {layout:false});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { authenticated: false});
   console.log('index');
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res){
  res.render('login');
  console.log('login'); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

example of jade

layout jade

```
 doctype
 html
   head
     title Przykład MongoDB
   body
     h1 Moja
     hr
     block content
```

login jade

```
extends layout
block content

form(action="/login", method="POST")
    fieldset
        legend Logowanie
        p
            label Adres e-mail
            input(name="user[email]", type="text")
        p
            button Wyślij
        p
            a(href="/") Powrót
```

i use express 4.7.2 and jade 1.9.1 and i dont have any error or bugs when run node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your jade file seems to be wrong:

```
extends layout
block content
    form(action="/login", method="POST")
        fieldset
            legend Logowanie
            p
                label Adres e-mail
                input(name="user[email]", type="text")
            p
                button Wyślij
            p
                a(href="/") Powrót
```

There might be something else as well, but try this first.

Comment: You were right, maybe you have some experience with jade and angular? When i add ng app and controller to the layout the angular is not working on other views which extend layout until i add controller once again.?

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't know much about Angular, but if I were to take a guess, I'd say that you need to add ng-app and ng-controller to each individual view. np-app is probably common to all of the views (due to what it looks like from this post), but ng-controller should be attached to every individual view. As I said, I don't know much about Angular.